# Global minimum of a function - is this condition sufficient?

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose I have a smooth function $f:\ \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$, such that:

- $f'(x,y)  = 0$ if and only if $(x,y) = (0,0)$. (where of course $f'(x,y) = (\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(x,y),\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(x,y))$
- $f$ has a local minimum at $(0,0)$.

Does it follow that $f$ needs to have a *global* minimum at $(0,0)$? Of course, if we can show that $f(x,y) > f(0,0)$ for sufficiently large $x,y$ this follows immediately. Somehow, I can't see an argument why $f$ couldn't decrease along some path running off to $\infty$, but I also can't seem to construct an counterexample without making $f'$ vanish at some point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is necessary that $\nabla f$ vanishes at *exactly one* point.  Otherwise let $f(x,y)=x^3+y^2-xy$, critical values $(0,0)$, a saddle and $(1/6,1/12)$,a strict local minimum.  But for each fixed $y_0$ we have
$$\lim_{x\to-\infty}f(x,y_0)=-\infty.$$

You may want to plot $f$, quite interesting.